# Google Cloud VPC vs AWS VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Google Cloud & AWS have different implementation for a VPC. In GCP VPC are associated with projects. What's confusing me is that in a GCP project you can have two different VPC but with same subnet CIDR. If anyone has any resource which can clear my doubts please

Answer (score 1):

In GCP, 2 VPC networks in the same project must have different names, so they are distinguishable and completely independent/isolated. VMs in one VPC network have to go through external IP addresses to talk to VMs in other VPC network. Or you can connect them through VPC Peering, so that they can talk to each other through internal IPs. See:

[GCP - VPC Network Overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc).

[GCP - VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)

Answer (score 0):

A feature you can use in this case is to create a Peering in the VPC, this function will allows  internal IP address connectivity across two Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) networks regardless of whether they belong to the same project or the same organization.

VPC Network Peering enables you to connect VPC networks so that workloads in different VPC networks can communicate internally. Traffic stays within Google's network and doesn't traverse the public internet.

VPC Network Peering gives you several advantages over using external IP addresses or VPNs to connect networks, including: Network Latency,Network Security and Network Cost.

For information about Peering and VPC,see:

VPC: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc

Peering: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering